# Desktop application was immediately closing when trying to debug

Tags: apache-flex, air

I was working on an application and it was immediately closing. The console said:

> [Unload SWF] unknown

Answer (score 0):

In my compiler settings I had:

```
-swf-version=20
```

I changed that to

```
-swf-version=19
```

And it worked. It maybe crashing because I may not have SWF 20 playerglobal but I do have SWF 19 playerglobal.